# Difference between "and" and "where" in joins

Tags: sql, join

Whats the difference between

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1 
  FROM table1 cd  
  JOIN table2 
    ON     cd.Company = table2.Name 
       and table2.Id IN (2728)
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1 
  FROM table1 cd  
  JOIN table2 
    ON cd.Company = table2.Name 
 where table2.Id IN (2728)
```

both return the same result and both have the same explain output

Comment: Small tip: Have a look at the execution plan, that might give a bit more insight. SQL does a lot of query optimizations.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Firstly there is a semantic difference. When you have a join, you are saying that the relationship between the two tables is defined by that condition. So in your first example you are saying that the tables are related by `cd.Company = table2.Name AND table2.Id IN (2728)`. When you use the WHERE clause, you are saying that the relationship is defined by `cd.Company = table2.Name` and that you only want the rows where the condition `table2.Id IN (2728)` applies. Even though these give the same answer, it means very different things to a programmer reading your code.

In this case, the WHERE clause is almost certainly what you mean so you should use it.

Secondly there is actually difference in the result in the case that you use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN. If you include the second condition as part of the join, you will still get a result row if the condition fails - you will get values from the left table and nulls for the right table. If you include the condition as part of the WHERE clause and that condition fails, you won't get the row at all.

Here is an example to demonstrate this.

Query 1 (WHERE):

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1
  FROM table1 cd
  LEFT JOIN table2
    ON cd.Company = table2.Name
 WHERE table2.Id IN (2728);
```

Result:

```
field1
200
```

Query 2 (AND):

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1
  FROM table1 cd
  LEFT JOIN table2
    ON cd.Company = table2.Name
   AND table2.Id IN (2728);
```

Result:

```
field1
100
200
```

Test data used:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (Company NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Field1 INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (Company, Field1) VALUES
('FooSoft', 100),
('BarSoft', 200);

CREATE TABLE table2 (Id INT NOT NULL, Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table2 (Id, Name) VALUES
(2727, 'FooSoft'),
(2728, 'BarSoft');
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning LEFT JOINs. still I'll shamelessly point to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559194/difference-between-and-and-where-in-joins/2559769#2559769 for maybe even more details and reasons :)

Comment: In your example (query 2 with the AND) if we had table1.Id IN (100);  it would still returns two rows.. why is this?...

Comment: @psj01, that's because table1 is left joined in that query, so all rows of table1 will be included in the resultset irrespective of left join condition.

Answer (score 6):

SQL comes from [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).

One way to look at the difference is that JOINs are operations on sets that can produce more records or less records in the result than you had in the original tables. On the other side WHERE will always restrict the number of results.

The rest of the text is extra explanation.

---

For overview of join types see [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators) again.

When I said that the where condition will always restrict the results, you have to take into account that when we are talking about queries on two (or more) tables you have to somehow pair records from these tables even if there is no JOIN keyword.

So in SQL if the tables are simply separated by a comma, you are actually using a CROSS JOIN (cartesian product) which returns every row from one table for each row in the other.

And since this is a maximum number of combinations of rows from two tables then the results of any WHERE on cross joined tables can be expressed as a JOIN operation.

But hold, there are exceptions to this maximum when you introduce LEFT, RIGHT and FULL OUTER joins.

LEFT JOIN will join records from the left table on a given criteria with records from the right table, BUT if the join criteria, looking at a row from the left table is not satisfied for any records in the right table the LEFT JOIN will still return a record from the left table and in the columns that would come from the right table it will return NULLs (RIGHT JOIN works similarly but from the other side, FULL OUTER works like both at the same time).

Since the default cross join does NOT return those records you can not express these join criteria with WHERE condition and you are forced to use JOIN syntax (oracle was an exception to this with an extension to SQL standard and to = operator, but this was not accepted by other vendors nor the standard).

Also, joins usually, but not always, coincide with existing referential integrity and suggest relationships between entities, but I would not put as much weight into that since the where conditions can do the same (except in the before mentioned case) and to a good RDBMS it will not make a difference where you specify your criteria.

Answer (score 5):

- The  join is used to reflect the entity relations
- the where clause filters down results.

So the join clauses are 'static' (unless the entity relations change),
 while the where clauses are use-case specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. "ON" is like a synonym for "WHERE", so t he second kind of reads like:

`JOIN table2 WHERE cd.Company = table2.Name AND table2.Id IN (2728)`

Comment: According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html it doesn't seem like ON is a synonym for WHERE.

Comment: I said it is "like" a synonym.

Comment: and just for joins.inner joins.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference when the query optimisation engine breaks it down to its relevant query operators.